# libgdx make functions to a separate class

Tags: java, libgdx

So i have this code

```
public class MyGdxGame implements ApplicationListener {
private SpriteBatch batch;
private Texture grasstext;
private GrassField field;

@Override
public void create() {      

    batch = new SpriteBatch();

    grasstext = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/grassA.png"));

    field = new GrassField();
}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    batch.dispose();
    grasstext.dispose();
}
@Override
public void render() {      
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    //DrawField(100,10,3,3,31);
    //DrawField(200,50,4,2,31);
    field.DrawField(10, 10, 3, 5, 31);
}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
}

@Override
public void pause() {
}

@Override
public void resume() {
}

public void DrawField(int x,int y,int width,int height,int value)
{
    for(int xt=0;xt<width;xt++)
    {
        for(int yt=0;yt<height;yt++)
        {
            batch.begin();
            batch.draw(grasstext,((x+xt)+xt*value),((y+yt)+yt*value));
            batch.end();
        }
    }
}
```

and i want to be able to call the function "DrawField" from another class . i tried making a new class that contains the same code as in this function , making an object out of it and calling the function but i get a null pointer exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can just guess what you did so it would be great if you could put in the code of your new class (I guess it is GrassField), but have you checked if the objects batch (SpriteBatch) and grasstext (Texture) are available in GrassField? As far as i can see you are using a constructor without any parameters and i can not see any methods that contain the needed references. You can try to add the needed objects either with the constructor or with a seperate method of GrassField. It could look something like that:

```
public class GrassField {
private SpriteBatch batch;
private Texture grassText;

public GrassField(SpriteBatch batch, Texture grassText) {
    ...
    this.grassText = grassText;
    this.batch = batch;
    ...
}

..........
```

}